# How to monitor svnserve.exe?

Tags: windows, svn

I have a subversion server on Windows (CollabNet download 1.6.16 on Windows Server 2003), and it regulary starts using up 100% CPU for hours. Sadly, there is no logfile for svnserve.exe, nor a possibility to see what he is working on (AFAIK).

How do i found out

- what he is doing?
- what he was doing?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a log file. Add `--log-file <path>` to the point where svnserve.exe is launched. Also, running it with `--foreground` temporarily can be useful in seeing what's happening as it happens.

Comment: +1 Thanks... I didn't find anything about the option in the docs, but I should have tried to use the --help option, since the command comes from the unix world.